# How to implement generic function to instantiate TypedArrays

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to write a function like this:

```
export function createTypedArray<T extends TypedArray>( arg : { source : T, arraySize : number } ) : T {
  if( arg.source instanceof Int32Array ) {
    return new Int32Array( arg.arraySize );
  }
  if( arg.source instanceof Float32Array ) {
    return new Float32Array( arg.arraySize );
  }
  if( arg.source instanceof Float64Array ) {
    return new Float64Array( arg.arraySize );
  }
  throw 'Unsupported typed array type!';
}
```

The problem is that the typescript compiler is giving me errors like these:

**Type 'Int32Array' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'Int32Array' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'TypedArray'.ts(2322)**

I noticed that I can get rid of the errors if I add  like this:

```
return <T> new Int32Array( arg.arraySize );
```

Is there a better way to write this function?

Is there a way to write it somehow like this:

```
export function createTypedArray<T extends TypedArray>( arg : { source : T, arraySize : number } ) : T {
  if( arg.source instanceof Int32Array ||
      arg.source instanceof Float32Array ||
      arg.source instanceof Float64Array
  ) {
    return new <T>( arg.arraySize );
  }
  throw 'Unsupported typed array type!';
}
```

Comment: As far as I know and [as far as this open issues states](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15402), there is no `TypedArray` based class. Can you clarify what you did? Perhaps you defined  union type not shown? e.g. `type TypedArray = Int32Array | Float32Array | Float64Array`

Comment: I'm using ThreeJS which defines a TypedArray here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/02abc250eb919325a25c501fbda63cee8888d692/src/polyfills.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is because you have a misunderstanding of [`instanceof` type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards). They narrow the type of the variable on the left-hand-side, which in your case is `arg.source`. The type guard does NOT narrow the type of the type variable `T`.*

So in any situation where Typescript isn't smart enough to logically deduce the type of something, *but you can*, that is exactly when you are supposed to use type assertions. So

```
return new Int32Array( arg.arraySize ) as T
```

is *exactly* what you are supposed to do!

---

*Arguably it should, since `T` must be the type of `arg.source` -- perhaps you can submit this to the Typescript team.

Comment: This probably doesn't need its own issue; [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) covers the situation where narrowing variables will never narrow generic type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pain point in implementing generic functions where the generic type parameter is of a union type.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085) for more information.  The basic problem is that while it *may* be possible for the compiler to narrow the type of `arg.source` to, say, `Int32Array`, the compiler *cannot* narrow the generic type parameter from `T extends TypedArray` to something like `T extends Int32Array`.  In *general* it's not safe to narrow `T` when you narrow a value of type `T`, but in many instances like yours it would be very convenient to do this.  For now it doesn't happen though.

To take your existing implementation and make it compile, you can use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) the way you did.

---

If that was all I was going to say I'd've let the other answer stand, but I wanted to show that if you're willing to twist your implementation into pretzels to guide the compiler through your logic, you can get something that's at least vaguely type safe without an assertion:

```
const typedArrayMaker = (size: number) => ({
    get Int32Array() { return new Int32Array(size); },
    get Float32Array() { return new Float32Array(size); },
    get Float64Array() { return new Float64Array(size); }
});    
export function createTypedArray<K extends keyof ReturnType<typeof typedArrayMaker>>(
    arg: { source: { [Symbol.toStringTag]: K }, arraySize: number }) {
    return typedArrayMaker(arg.arraySize)[arg.source[Symbol.toStringTag]];
}
```

Here we build a `typedArrayMaker` function which, given a size, returns an object with [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) methods, one for each type of array you'd like to be able to make.  The compiler sees the type of `typedArrayMaker` as

```
const typedArrayMaker: (size: number) => {
    readonly Int32Array: Int32Array;
    readonly Float32Array: Float32Array;
    readonly Float64Array: Float64Array;
}
```

Then the `createTypedArray()` function takes the same argument as before, but the generic parameter is `K`, the value of the [`[Symbol.toStringTag]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) property of `arg.source`.  All typed arrays are known to have such a [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) value for this property.  And that's what we use to index into `typedArrayMaker`.

All this turns the return type into a generic *indexing* operation, which it can actually reason about. You end up with a return type that depends on `K`, with no errors.  Let's test it:

```
function test(i32: Int32Array, f32: Float32Array, f64: Float64Array, i8: Int8Array) {
    const i32New = createTypedArray({ source: i32, arraySize: 128 }); // Int32Array
    const f32New = createTypedArray({ source: f32, arraySize: 128 }); // Float32Array
    const f64New = createTypedArray({ source: f64, arraySize: 128 }); // Float64Array
    const i8New = createTypedArray({ source: i8, arraySize: 128 }); // error!
    // ----------------------------> ~~~~~~
    // Type '"Int8Array"' is not assignable to type 
    // '"Int32Array" | "Float32Array" | "Float64Array"'
}
```

You can see that the compiler recognizes that `i32New`, `f32New`, and `f64New` are of the expected types, while `i8` causes an error when being passed into `createTypedArray()` since that typed array type hasn't been included in our function yet.

Just thought it would be interesting to show one way to do it in a way the compiler understands.  In practice I would 100% definitely recommend using a type assertion because higher-order-functions-with-getters-and-symbol-properties are crazy.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApgEwIICdMEN4FkcBrZTGAXhgAoIBLAL2QC4YwBXAWwCNSBKCgHzUA3gFgAUDCkwA5slgBJMFADMAJiy54VfsJiZ5bTGFbIA7jCWqN2PDQbJeAbhgBfADQTps+TABiADYgONaadrr6hsamFoHBobbadIzObp6S0nKwcSEAbAAsYdoRBlBGJmDm-kF5hYn2KS6uEq7OEhLIAB6IIJiwAGZsYMBQtOAwwAYhyAAqSGhFADwA0jBdUMhgqBAwJPAg-TAASlFgcyiLCCgHcPMYiYQkmAICVF7SOJgyLHoQIEbAZgwPQAbQAyvBuCAAgA6KAgMFQTC0MAyGY4GQAXRYqw8ME+WjBDhY7G4pDcuneUlK5VuKHuWkepConxkMIJeCJKRBrJhfwByHBkK40LhCKRKLRGMxmKcLXa4kGw1G4w20CotHULCs6iK7hg-S11XiusS+v6BRYOSgBT1MFoAA5tcoHUVKRkpKBILBNWoAHJVSiTZDTc4Leq-f6YQEsX36jnwLlAgCMagdFJcAHpM5ZlKatFSJuBoAb1AGLEGphswwy7JGBSxDWp44kkyxU+nWlmc9b83hC16Sxb8uWKBMq7M7kUqPXo0Dhy3CcSYB2MzBs8bakUB8WfQ7R5WQ9WpxGYPy57GHYvOcvV131znSJhegBCQsbgC0X+-P9-f--QgAH7ASB745mGMAAOQAERWK6iTQZB9o7GAICwDgEB0DIYA4FwATIHAIB0gRYFQbBeY2Fo0EwAAPjA0G9pReDUXRDE1DadRUZB8riAqMBAA)

Comment: i appreciate the effort by why would you do that when the type assertion solution is not only shorter, is less complicated, not headache inducing and thoroughly type safe (i.e. you can't improve upon its type safety).

Comment: Maybe we're using "type safe" differently.  Type assertions specifically allow you to say that an expression is of a narrower type than the compiler can verify (i.e., downcasting).  This shifts the burden of responsibility for type safety from the compiler to the developer, and the developer can easily lie to the compiler (e.g., `if (arg.source instanceof Float32Array) { return new Int32Array( arg.arraySize ) as T }`) and the compiler will not give an error.  A conscientious function implementer can ensure that callers have type safety, but does not have such safety herself.

Comment: Also I'd be careful claiming "thoroughly" type safe. I often regret making such claims. For example, `class I32WithCheese extends Int32Array { cheese = "cheddar"; }` makes a subclass of `Int32Array`, and if you use one: `const i = new I32WithCheese([]); const a = createTypedArray({ source: i, arraySize: 128 });` you have a value `a` that the compiler *erroneously* thinks has a `cheese` property because of the type assertions: `a.cheese.toUpperCase()` errors at runtime but gives you no compiler warning. [Oops.](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-chk67?file=/index.ts)

Comment: I stand corrected. Please edit your answer so I can switch my vote.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do given your example

You have

```
function createTypedArray<T extends TypedArray>(
      arg : { source : T, arraySize : number } ) : T
```

Which looks like you'd call it like this

```
const someExistingArray = new Float32Array(12);
const v = createTypedArray({
   source: someExistingArray,   // ???
   arraySize: 40,
});
```

It's not clear why you'd want to pass an existing array when all you're getting from it is the type.

But, that said, this seems to work

```
type TypedArray = Int8Array | Uint8Array | Int16Array | Uint16Array | Int32Array | Uint32Array | Float32Array;

function createTypedArray<T extends TypedArray>(arg: { source: T, arraySize: number }): T {
  const {source, arraySize} = arg;
  return new (Object.getPrototypeOf(source).constructor)(arraySize);
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)